# Collectionview is crashed after applying autolayout

Tags: swift, uitableview, collections

1. I have added collectionview inside tableview.During scrolling collection is crashed. I am getting error mentioned below.
2. **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'**
3. I have tried  all lines of code mentioned below.
4. `collectionView.reloadData()
   collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
   collectionView.layoutSubviews()`
5. But nothing happened.
6. I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for calculating row height of tableview.To solve this crash I have given harded coded height to tableview row = 150.
7. After this it works fine but i want to  solve it with help UITableViewAutomaticDimension.So that acccording to data different height of the row is created.

**[image: different height of row]**

Comment: try using reloadSections instead of reloadData

Comment: i have tried  reloadSections also but nothing happned..

Comment: try to invalidate just before the layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: i am using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout for this . func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return collectionView.frame.size
    }

Comment: show the code for your tableView cell with the collection - not sure why it crashes, but you should be aware that `collectionView` does not have intrinsic content size, so just by itself you cannot use it to determine the size of the tableView cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was setting the constraints the by code and accidentally  i write  invalidateLayout() in the wrong place. So invalidateLayout is working fine.

`collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

[image]